# MikroTik routerboard - offline network, iOS and Android message 'no internet available'

Tags: android, ios, mikrotik-routeros

We have an application that uses a MiktroTik router without any uplink. It's an internal network. A computer (aka web-server) connects to the router and users connect with the Wifi from the router and login via Chrome / Safari on the server.

When users are connecting to the router they get a message that there is no internet available.

Does anyone know how Apple and Android determine that there is no internet?
And how you can spoof this that the user devices 'thinks' that there is an internet connection?

Comment: Its not limited to android or ios. Windows will also report that there is no internet.